# Packet & Function Conflict

Tags: php

I'm back, this time working on a game and I came across a problem. So I was tracing some packets, and made a duplicate on my source. So, the function:

```
function handleBakeryStateUpdate( $data, $str, $clientid )
{
    $client    = $this->clients[ $clientid ]; //$client SHOULD ALWAYS BE A MEMBER OF THE CLIENT CLASS!
    $this->sendToRoom( $client->extRoomID, "%xt%barsu%" . $client->ID . "%"{'CurrentStation':'IngredientsStation','IngredientsStation':[{'IngredientType':'Eggs','TotalRequired':1,'CurrentCount':0},{'IngredientType':'Milk','TotalRequired':1,'CurrentCount':0},{'IngredientType':'Hay','TotalRequired':1,'CurrentCount':0},{'IngredientType':'Flour','TotalRequired':1,'CurrentCount':0}],'CheerStation':{'CheerCapacity':7,'CurrentCheerCount':7,'Emote':7},'MultiplierStation':{'Counter':-1,'Multiplier':'Small'}}"%" );
}
```

The packet is supposed to send a bunch of stuff, and in that packet it has { and }. And, the other problem is that the function also has { and }. So it gives me:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in ...
```

How can I fix this?

More information: The packet it is sending is all this:

```
{'CurrentStation':'IngredientsStation','IngredientsStation':[{'IngredientType':'Eggs','TotalRequired':1,'CurrentCount':0},{'IngredientType':'Milk','TotalRequired':1,'CurrentCount':0},{'IngredientType':'Hay','TotalRequired':1,'CurrentCount':0},{'IngredientType':'Flour','TotalRequired':1,'CurrentCount':0}],'CheerStation':{'CheerCapacity':7,'CurrentCheerCount':7,'Emote':7},'MultiplierStation':{'Counter':-1,'Multiplier':'Small'}}
```

Thank you.

Comment: what are the `"%"` at each end of that string meant to be?

Comment: Your data appears to be in JSON, meaning there are lots of ways to handle it in PHP (e.g. [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert it to a PHP array). . . it's unclear what `sendToRoom` is expecting, and how you're hoping to pass it, making this question very difficult to answer.

Comment: In the packets, it separates everything sent. Those are in all the packets, they separate everything sent.

Comment: I think you need to add quotes to the string "{json data here}".

Answer (score 1):

If you literally just want to pass the JSON as a string that's encapsulated in percent symbols, then:

```
function handleBakeryStateUpdate( $data, $str, $clientid )
{
    $client    = $this->clients[ $clientid ]; //$client SHOULD ALWAYS BE A MEMBER OF THE CLIENT CLASS!
    $this->sendToRoom( $client->extRoomID, "%xt%barsu%" . $client->ID . "%" . "{'CurrentStation':'IngredientsStation','IngredientsStation':[{'IngredientType':'Eggs','TotalRequired':1,'CurrentCount':0},{'IngredientType':'Milk','TotalRequired':1,'CurrentCount':0},{'IngredientType':'Hay','TotalRequired':1,'CurrentCount':0},{'IngredientType':'Flour','TotalRequired':1,'CurrentCount':0}],'CheerStation':{'CheerCapacity':7,'CurrentCheerCount':7,'Emote':7},'MultiplierStation':{'Counter':-1,'Multiplier':'Small'}}" . "%" );
}
```

I somehow doubt that's actually want you want, but unless you show what `sendToRoom` is expecting, that's the best answer I can give.

Also note that using "packet" the way you are is very confusing.  You're really just passing a string to a function.  The use of the word packet is confusing, since it has a very specific meaning when it comes to networking.

Comment: SendRoom is basically to send it to all the users in the room. You don't have to mind about that.

Comment: @iamsoawesome, you should consider accepting an answer if it gave you the desired solution.